# Why can't we use abstract class instead of interface in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

In WCF, why can't we use abstract class instead of interfaces as a service contract and why should we specify all the service contracts(interfaces) in the contract in the endpoint element while configuring WCF service? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ServiceContract and OperationContract can be used on abstract classes and the code will compile successfully because according to the C# compiler there is nothing wrong. **However** while hosting the service, the ServiceHost **will throw an exception** because according to WCF rules - if a class has been marked with a ServiceContract attribute then another class cannot inherit from it.

Bottom line - it's not supported. You need to use interfaces.

Comment: Well I think the unstated fact is you cannot support state in your service contracts, which an abstract class allows.

Answer (score 2):

This goes to the very basic of OOP. If You use abstract class it will compile but while run time it will throw an exception saying

> Inheritance can only be used among interface types.If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, then another service class cannot derive from it

That is only possible in case of interfaces.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you down voted my answer ? Should I remove it, if it is not descriptive enough for you?

Comment: Not sure who voted down, but it may have something to do with your claim that this goes to the very heart of OOP but then don't go into more detail about what that means. If you removed that particular comment then your answer is more to the point.